# Install Scratch 2 under Linux Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, adobe, mit-scratch

I tried to install Scratch 2 under Linux for Education at school. I followed [these good instructions](https://gist.github.com/jiggneshhgohel/ade2c57d03c4ad895e82) to install Adobe Air - everything works fine. But if I execute the Air-Installfile for Scratch I will be asked for the root password. In the little Pop-Up-Window it's not working so I tried to start the Air-File with these:

```
/opt/Adobe\ AIR/Versions/1.0/Adobe\ AIR\ Application\ Installer /{absolute path to downloadfolder}/Scratch.air
```

It works fine, but I get an error saying error that my Scratch-Install-File is broken... I re-loaded again but nothing changed. Does someone has an helpful idea?

Comment: You could try at http://askubuntu.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your file size. The download have maybe been interupted before it was complete. It happened to me so I downloaded it again with a download manager like JDownloader and installed it successfully but only with sudo

> sudo /opt/Adobe\ AIR/Versions/1.0/Adobe\ AIR\ Application\ Installer /{absolute path to downloadfolder}/Scratch.air

The problem is that you can't launch it directly when you installed it with sudo rights. I'm looking for a solution but this is another problem.